# How does eventbrite's organizer_get function work?

Tags: api, eventbrite

I haven't been able to get eventbrite's /organizer_get API endpoint to give me back a successful result. I've included the app_key just like with all other api requests.

https://www.eventbrite.com/json/organizer_get?id=52803052&app_key=FOO
(replacing FOO with the actual app_key)

{"error": {"error_type": "Not Found", "error_message": "Invalid email and/or password."}}

(but it is valid: http://www.eventbrite.com/org/52803052?s=8134061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note, I work on the platform team at Eventbrite.
```

Currently, `organizer_get` only returns a result if the client making the request is the owner of the organizer record.  If you have an organizer account/id and make a request with that organizer id, it will work.

This is, obviously, quite unintuitive and not documented at all.  I'll look into lifting this restriction or at the very least documenting the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible today to get additional data for organizers such as profile images, social network accounts, website, etc? (This information all visible publicly on the website)

Comment: The API doesn't return that data as of now.  Feel free to contact api@eventbrite.com if you have some specific needs.